# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause (Ms sql + Superset)

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-superset

I have a table **offset_table** in which the offset in minutes are written. This table will have exactly 1 record and 1 column.

So I need to add those number of minutes into the **registration_time**.

I have tried it using following approaches. But no luck.

**Approach 1 :**

```
    SELECT 
    DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,(select offset from offset_table) , registration_time) as date)) as weeknumber
    FROM 
    registration
    GROUP BY
    DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,(select offset from offset_table)  , registration_time) as date));
```

**Error :**
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

**Approach 2 :**

```
    SELECT 
    DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,(select offset from offset_table) , registration_time) as date)) as weeknumber
    FROM 
    registration
    GROUP BY
    weeknumber;
```

**Error :**
Invalid column name 'weeknumber'.

**Approach 3 :**

```
DECLARE @offsetInMin int;
SET @offsetInMin = (select offset from offset_table);

 SELECT 
    DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,@offsetInMin , registration_time) as date)) as weeknumber
    FROM 
    registration
    GROUP BY
    DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,@offsetInMin  , registration_time) as date));
```

**Issue with Approach 3 :** This query works fine. But problem is this , I need this query in Apache Superset as virtual table query. So If I declare the variable then it gives error on superset.

**Error**: Virtual dataset query cannot consist of multiple statements"

So please guide me how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Why not `CROSS JOIN` to the table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Larnu mentoined, you can `CROSS JOIN` the offset_table, since it only contains 1 value. I am assuming you need the `GROUP BY` to do an aggregation? If not, you do not need to use `GROUP BY` here at all. If you want to avoid getting duplicate records, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, offset_table.offset, registration_time) as date)) as weeknumber
FROM 
registration
CROSS JOIN offset_table
GROUP BY
DATEPART(week, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, offset_table.offset, registration_time) as date));
```